# Можно ли как то продолжить выполнение кода после if

Tags: javascript, node.js

у меня сложилась ситуация:

```
if(!Data){
//add data
}
message.channel.send()
```

Есть ли что-то на подобии continue

```
if(!Data){
//add data
continue;
}
message.channel.send()
```

Это очень важно,готов даже через костыли делать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, можно. Более того, этого стандартное поведение во всех языках. Никакие continue  для этого не нужны, код и так будет выполняться.

Comment: Спасибо за помочь

Comment: Также можно использовать `else` ветвление. https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else